# recorrer contar, sumar y promediar sobre un DataFrame python

Tags: dataframe

Supongamos que tengo el siguiente df:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'col_1':['a','a', 'a', 'a','a','a','b','b', 'b', 'b','b','b'],
                 'col_2':[1,1,1, 1,1,1, 2,2,2, 2,2,2],
                 'col_3':[1,0,0, 1,1,0, 0,1,2, 1,1,2]})
```

y quiero que para cada valor de la columna 1 (a y b) me compruebe si los valores de la columna 2 son mayores a los de la columna 3, si se cumple, entonces que me devuelva un dataframe con dos columna donde la primera sea a o b y la segunda sea lo siguiente: Para el caso **a** el segundo y el tercer valor cumplen la condición, así que me ponga un 2, luego el sexto valor también la cumple, me coloca un 1, lo sume 2+1 y lo divida por 2 que es el numero de veces que se cumple la condición. Para el caso **b** lo cumplen el 1 y 2 y el 4 y 5, así que seria (2+2)/2
De esta forma el dataframe me queda como, por ejemplo:

columna1    columna2

a             1.5

b              2

Espero que se entienda.
Gracias

Answer (score 0):

He hecho esta pequeña chapuza. Estoy seguro que existen métodos elegantes para hacer esto, pero mis conocimientos son muy limitados. He optado por ignorar la columna 1 de momento.

```
# creo una columna de ceros y unos y se la añado al DF
col_4 = []

for i, w in enumerate(df.col_2):
    if df.col_2[i]>df.col_3[i]:
        col_4.append(1)        
    else:
        col_4.append(0)

df['col_4']=col_4
# creo una lista en la cual almaceno la suma de los unos que aparecen consecutivamente
a=[]
suma=0

for num in lst:
    if num == 1:
        suma+=1

    else:
        if suma!=0:
            a.append(suma)
        suma=0
```

Ahora tengo una lista que solo tengo que sumar y dividir por su longitud

A ver si alguien tiene un método elegante para hacer esto.

Gracias!!